# Url changed but page remains same

Tags: .htaccess, url, rewriting

I want to change my url

```
http://www.abc.com/search_result.php?id=110

to

http://www.abc.com/110
```

Here is the code which i am using.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+search_result\.php\?id=([^\s]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://abc.com/%1? [R=301,L]
```

But the problem is, url changed to http://www.abc.com/110  , but page remain same.

Please anybody help !

One thing more i want to ask . Suppose i want to add more parameter in original url:
 Say,

```
http://www.abc.com/search_result.php?id=110&name=amit
```

then what i should do to get the result.

```
http://www.abc.com/i-am-amit
```

Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need an internal rewrite rule also for showing actual content from `search_result.php`"

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+search_result\.php\?id=([^&\s]+)\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://abc.com/%1? [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ search_result.php?id=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
```

Also for `http://www.abc.com/search_result.php?id=110&name=amit` how do you want pretty URL to be? Keep in mind that you will need both id & name in pretty URL such as:

`http://www.abc.com/110/amit`

Is that how you want?

Comment: Hi, @ anubhava , i have raised a problem , if possible please go through it.